# Unable to install rvm-rbx in ubuntu 11.10

Tags: rvm, ubuntu-11.10

When i run the "rvm install rbx-head" in my ubuntu 11.10.There seems to be some error in the installation
errors as follows:

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ferramroberto/filezilla/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ferramroberto/filezilla/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

As i don't have more reputation, i was unable to post the error lines which contain links.

Comment: That repo doesn't have packages for your Ubuntu version.

Comment: may i know, can i able to do install this rvm-rbx in ubuntu or not?

Comment: can i able to Install Pelusa in ubuntu 11.10 or not. Thanks in advance

Comment: make sure you can get: `sudo apt-get update` working first